# Correlation test for dataframes of different dimensions in R

Tags: r, correlation, ranking

I have two dataframes in R, each containing a ranking of the variables from highest to lowest. Here are two simple examples of them:

Cali_Income

```
County    Income   Rank
county a       46000     1
county b       29000     3
county c       33000     2
```

Cali_Asthma_Rates

```
County   Diagnoses  Rank
county a      0.100       4
county b      0.200       1
county c      0.150       3
county d      0.190       2
county e      0.080       5
```

I want to see if there is any correlation between the two rankings of the counties, but the Cali_Asthma_Rates data has more variables, so when I try the following I get an "incompatible dimensions" error:

```
cor(as.numeric(Cali_Asthma_Rates$Rank), as.numeric(Cali_Income$Rank), method="spearman")
```

Is there a way to find correlation between the ranks without removing the extra counties from Cali_Asthma_Rates? I am basically just trying to find any sort of statistical method to see whether or not the counties that rank high in Cali_Income also rank high in Cali_Asthma_Rates. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should start by merging the two data frames:

```
Cali_combined <- merge(Cali_Income, Cali_Asthma_Rates,
  by = `County Name`,
  suffixes = c(".Income", ".Asthma_Rate"))
head(Cali_combined)
```

(note: fix the by to be your header for "County Name" if there is an underscore or something that I didn't see)

Then, you can do your correlation on the pairwise complete observations (for example)

```
with(Cali_combined, 
  cor(Rank.Income, Rank.Asthma_Rate,
    use = "pairwise.complete.obs",
    method = "spearman")
)
```

Look at `?cor` for other options on which observations to use, but for only 2 variables, this is equivalent to `complete.obs`.

Comment: Yes "County Name" was a typo, I fixed it on my post. When I merged the two data frames as you did above, the resulting Cali_Combined had 0 rows. Any ideas why it might not be working?